# Cannot access tor control port when tor is running as a daemon

Tags: python, tor, pytorctl

```
ipdb>conn = TorCtl.connect(controlAddr="127.0.0.1", controlPort=9051, passphrase="zazaking")
ipdb>Connection refused. Is the ControlPort enabled?
```

but when running tor in the shell session, with the configuration file indicated explicitly everything works fine.

Am I missing something here?.

In the terminal:

```
$ tor -f /etc/tor/torrc
```

---

```
ipdb> conn = TorCtl.connect(controlAddr="127.0.0.1", controlPort=9051, passphrase="zazaking")
ipdb> conn
<TorCtl.TorCtl.Connection instance at 0x7fcb947a1e18>
```

Comment: Do both processes use the same torrc? What operating system do you use?

Comment: Ubuntu, yes, log says they do